# My '/etc/resolv.conf' file has stopped updating itself in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, ubuntu-unity

I did a silly thing: I manually updated my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and now it isn’t updating anymore.

Before I did that, it was generated by the NetworkManager GUI of my Ubuntu 14.04.3 Unity desktop.

What should I do to get it populated automatically again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to regenerate it by running this command:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

But perhaps the permissions on the file `resolv.conf` itself are screwy. So just blow away that file like this:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then run `sudo resolvconf -u` again.

And if somehow this doesn’t work, run this `dpkg-reconfigure` command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Just punch through the prompts, reboot the machine and see what happens.

Comment: After doing that, I get  "# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)" in the file, but no nameservers yet

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: Yes, that and a reboot.